# Dynamic JS-base HTML template with vite?

Tags: vite

html-webpack-plugin supports JS-based templates (where index HTML code is produced by executing JS module code).

Is it possible with Vite? Haven't found it in existing plugins, maybe someone could give advice.

UPD:

It seems like it is possible if to inject html in `transformIndexHtml.transform` statically loaded (in vite.config.js) module. Though it works, the execution of the template code is done in the the context `vite.config` (nodejs) on the build, though maybe this is not a problem)